# How common is it for cats to snore?

Tags: cats, sleep, snoring

I've noticed lately that both of my adult, non-elderly cats tend to snore when sleeping.  Usually they're sleeping on their sides or curled up when this happens.  (I don't notice it in "meatloaf" position, and they don't sleep on their backs.)  They don't appear to be in any distress, and we've just been to the vet for a routine exam and gotten a clean bill of health.  Is snoring normal?  Are there particular factors that affect it, like diet or environment?

We did get told that they're both a bit overweight and we'll be taking measures to deal with that.  But we're not talking Garfield-class cats here; they should each lose a pound or so.  (They're both 13-pound regular domestic housecats, no identifiable breed.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Stertor](http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/respiratory/c_ct_noisy_breathing#.Us4DfWRDv48), also known as snoring, isn't as common in cats as with dogs, but there are no obvious age/breed/sex patterns to it and it's well known, though being overweight can exacerbate the condition. In general, there are surgical treatments for it (not surprising, the same is true for us), but if they're not distressed and generally healthy, I wouldn't be considering that. If you've talked to the vet and they're also not concerned, then, well, hopefully they don't keep you awake at night. :D

One thing, however, is that it may signal is a possible issue for them: narrowing of the nasal passages (with the delightfully unpronounceable name of *[Nasopharyngeal Stenosis](https://www.google.ca/#q=nasopharyngeal%20stenosis%20cats)* being the clinical term). Cats of any breed, age, or sex can have this and a possible sign of it is whistling or snoring sounds when breathing (there are other signs that may or may not be present). However, it is triggered usually by an upper respiratory illness or some foreign body or irritant in the area. Probably a red-herring, but if you know your cat's history, you may consider that something to have looked at.

Answer (score 1):

I have had several cats that snore.  It sometimes gets worse with age.

A dramatic change might be due to a serious medical cause - like a cold.  But since you have checked that out, I wouldn't worry about it.